# Give warning or report an error when an attribute is applied on a C# class

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

Say I define an attribute as follows.

```cs
public class LogAttribute : System.Attribute { }
```

And say I decorate a class as follows with it.

```cs
[Log]
public class MyClass : IMyInterface { }
```

I want a compiler warning(or may be an error) be generated when I apply that attribute on a class that does not implement any interface.

So the above should **not** generate any warning, because the MyClass implements IMyInterface.

But it should generate a warning if the class does not implement any interface, so it should generate a warning in the following case.

```cs
[Log]
public class SomeOtherClass { }
```

Simply want to put a constraint that the attribute must be used only on  a class when it implements an interface and cannot otherwise.

I guess its possible with Roslyn Analyzer and was [looking at these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) but not sure where to start.

Can someone nudge me or show some examples please?

### Update

For example I was trying to understand more about syntax trees, I got the following suggestion.

[image: Roslyn Analyzer Suggestion]

And accordingly I rewrote the method call.

This is what I am looking for. How do we do this.

I searched a bit. I found [this exact warning RS1034 in the docs here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.md#rs1034-prefer-iskind-for-checking-syntax-kinds).

I also looked into the [source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/634c37a5818bf063c322a0aa1c77e93dd0dd8550/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/CSharpExtensions.cs#L209), but there is nothing unusual about it.

Comment: Did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Comment: Yes, I started with it, but not sure I am in the right direction. Did not complete it yet though.

Comment: Learn by example, find a very simple analyzer and run it, https://github.com/Cybermaxs/awesome-analyzers